# Flutter - Trying to call function as soon as user gets redirected to homepage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

When my app launches, it checks if the user is logged in. It's basically a page with a progress indicator until it pushes to the actual homepage. `initState()` looks like this:

```
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((firebaseUser) {
      if (firebaseUser == null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LogInPage()));
      } else {
        String userID = firebaseUser.uid;
        AppConstants.currentUser = User(id: userID);
        AppConstants.currentUser.getLoginPush().whenComplete(() {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GuestHomePage(index: 0)));
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

On the 8th line, getLoginPush() does something like this:

```
 Future<void> getLoginPush() async {
   await getUserInfoFromFirestore();
   await getImageFromStorage();
  }
```

It basically just gets the user's image and some basic user information.

My question is, how can I add a function similar to `getLoginPush()` (call it `getRestOfInfo()` for now) after Navigator.pushReplacement when the app pushes to the homepage? The reason why I don't have `getLoginPush()` & `getRestOfInfo()` as one function is because `getRestOfInfo()` gets bookings and saved postings. The more a user saves or makes bookings, the longer it takes to redirect to the homepage. Hoping to find a solution to avoid a long load time until the user gets redirected to the app homepage.

Just looking for the best course of action to take here. This is my first time developing an application, so any help and guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.
Heidi

Comment: you can redirect immediately and load from homepage inside initState, till the data is loading you can show progress

Comment: As @Henok suggested you can use loading screen like this. https://github.com/ShalikaAshan01/Daily-Diary/blob/5690161439b92d198584029818d3fe4b8a906db2/lib/main.dart#L42

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Lead me on the right path, and I just have a few things to figure out. Thanks!